# Project throwing error on Maven compilation in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ as IDE. I have placed jar files in m2 repository and created maven configuration:

[image]

I have placed jar files in m2 repository but when I am compiling the project it's throwing error for some packages not found.  I have made sure that packages are there in m2 repository but still getting the errors.

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler- plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myproject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>   [ERROR] /D:/Users/abhivash/Projects/SalesExpress/sales-express/src/main/java/com/amind/att/service/csi/CreateEnterpriseBillPreviewHandler.java:[18,83] package com.cingular.csi.csi.namespaces.fobpmorders._203_0.wsdl.fobpmorderscsi_wsdl does not exist

Comment: make sure the version and the folder structure in m2 repository matches the artifact types in pom file.

Comment: I don't know if you mean installed but be sure you really installed the jars and not just dropped it in the local repository. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: I have just dropped the files and adding repository path to local repository. Can you please help me what more to do in this command box . @meistermeier

Comment: Like it is written in the linked documentation (best guess sample): `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=dependency1.jar -DgroupId=com.cingular.csi -DartifactId=csi-namespaces -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar` afterwards you have to add the dependency to your project's pom file.